# How to write the below codes in code Igniter

Tags: php

```
SELECT *, FROM location WHERE date IN (SELECT MAX(date) 
FROM location GROUP BY user detail id);
```

I have written codes for the above but not working. Here is the code:

```
$this->db->order_by("date","desc");
$select= $this->db->select('*');
$this->db->group_by('userdetail_id');
$this->db->limit(1);  $qry = $this->db->get('location');
```

Comment: what was the error you are getting? Post it also

Answer (score 0):

You can write following way

```
$this->db->select('*');  
$this->db->where("date IN (SELECT MAX(date) FROM location GROUP BY userdetail_id) ",false,false);  
$this->db->limit(1);  
$this->db->order_by("date","desc");  
$qry = $this->db->get('location');
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'detail id)  
ORDER BY `date` DESC
 LIMIT 1' at line 3</p>
            <p>SELECT *
FROM `location`
WHERE date IN (SELECT MAX(date) FROM location GROUP BY user detail id)  
ORDER BY `date` DESC
 LIMIT 1

Comment: Please confirm this field userdetail_id

Answer (score 0):

Query Should be :

```
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->where_in("(SELECT MAX(date) FROM location GROUP BY userdetail_id)");
    $this->db->order_by("date","desc");
    $this->db->get('location')
```